# Elseif doesn't work properly

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to make form validation with ajax. 
Mine problem is elseif statement doesn't work properly

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //Create safe values for input into database
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['password']);
    $company = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['company']);
    $mail = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['mail']);
    $adress = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['adress']);

    $errorEmpty = false;
    $errorTaken = false;
    $errorMail = false;

    //Check are required fields empty
    if(empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($company) || empty($mail) || empty($adress)){
        echo "<span class='form-error'>Fill in all fields!</span>";
        $errorEmpty = true;
    }

    //Check is username already taken HERE IS THE PROBLEM!
    elseif(isset($_POST['username'])){

        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['username']);

        if(!empty($username)){

            $username_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username = '$username'");
            $count=mysqli_num_rows($username_query);

            if($count!=0)
            {
              echo"<span class='form-error'>Username is already taken! </span>";
              $errorTaken = true;
            }
    }

}
    //Check is mail adress correct
    elseif(!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<span class='form-error'> Write a valid e-mail adress!</span>";
        $errorMail = true;
    }
    else{
            //Create user
            $add_user_sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_username, user_password, user_company, user_mail, user_adress) 
                            VALUES ('".$username ."', '".$password."', '".$company."', '".$mail."', '".$adress."')";

            $add_user_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_user_sql)
                or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

            //Close connection to MySQL
            mysqli_close($mysqli);

            echo "<span class='form-success'>Succesifuly registrated!</span>";
        }
}
```

Problem is when i check is username already in database,because after that step every next elseif statement won't execute. When I put it on first place it stops execution of rest of code,same situation is when I put it on last place.Other conditions for checking empty fields and mail validation are working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Line that creates "problem" checks for your $_POST['username'].

```
elseif(isset($_POST['username'])){
```

If $_POST['username'] is set, the if-else statement won't go deeper (that's how it works).
I would suggest something like this, to solve your problem:

```
// check if it was sent through your form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    //Create safe values for input into database
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['password']);
    $company = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['company']);
    $mail = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['mail']);
    $adress = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['adress']);

    $errorEmpty = false;
    $errorTaken = false;
    $errorMail = false;

    // check if any of the fields are empty
    if(empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($company) || empty($mail) || empty($adress))
    {
        echo "<span class='form-error'>Fill in all fields!</span>";
        $errorEmpty = true;
    }

    //if none of the fields are empty - check if username exists
    $username_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username = '$username'");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($username_query);

    if($count!=0)
    {
        echo"<span class='form-error'>Username is already taken! </span>";
        $errorTaken = true;
    }


    //Check is mail adress correct
    if(!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        echo "<span class='form-error'> Write a valid e-mail adress!</span>";
        $errorMail = true;
    }


    // check if any of the errors are set to true
    if(!$errorEmpty AND !$errorMail AND !$errorTaken)
    {
        //Create user
        $add_user_sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_username, user_password, user_company, user_mail, user_adress) 
                         VALUES ('".$username ."', '".$password."', '".$company."', '".$mail."', '".$adress."')";

        $add_user_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_user_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

        //Close connection to MySQL
        mysqli_close($mysqli);

        echo "<span class='form-success'>Succesifuly registrated!</span>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Script check is username already taken fine but after that won't execute rest of script to check mail validation and add user to database.
With your code i get all 3 types of error :(

Comment: Try to add this line at the end: var_dump($username, $password, $company, $mail, $address, $errorEmpty, $errorTaken, $errorMail);
It should echo every value of every of these variables (even if it is null or true/false)- this will help us find the problem.

Comment: Added and get this if just press register get this (string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" NULL bool(true) bool(false) bool(false))


if try to register administrator which already is registrated get this(string(13) "administrator" string(5) "12345" string(13) "administrator" string(13) "administrator" NULL bool(false) bool(true) bool(false)

if try to register admin get this(string(13) "administrator" string(5) "12345" string(13) "administrator" string(13) "administrator" NULL bool(false) bool(true) bool(false)

Comment: NULL value is my fault- I have written $address, instead of your $adress.
But besides that- it seems that you are getting:
$errorEmpty while you send empty form
and $errorTaken when you type in administrator user (taken) - whitch seems to be working OK for me. Try typing user that isn't in db yet.

Comment: When i try to add user which is not in db yet i get this [string(5) "admin" string(5) "12345" string(5) "admin" string(5) "admin" NULL bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)].  Script doesn't check mail validation even if i enter wrong mail form. When i remove part with checking username in database everything works fine because of that i think there is some problem in that part of script

Comment: Does it output any errors? I can see from what you entered- that everything went fine. Try replacing $count!=0 with $count>0
Also, you can replace if(!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) with if(filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false). filter_var returns string if email is correct, false otherwise.

Comment: Well, all conditions work for me. I checked it without using any mysql connection, so the problem is probably with that part of code.
Your code _should_ output errors. Try echo'ing mysqli_error($mysqli) at the bottom (after user insert to db).

Comment: fixed,i will post new code as answer,but anyway thanks for willing to help you have +1 from me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Either try to run your script from the command line, or add this line at the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

in this way you can see which error is stopping the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed by writting this code,anyway thanks everyone for willing to help

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //Create safe values for input into database
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['password']);
    $company = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['company']);
    $mail = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['mail']);
    $adress = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['adress']);

    $errorEmpty = false;
    $errorTaken = false;
    $errorMail = false;

    //Check are required fields empty
    if(empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($company) || empty($mail) || empty($adress)){
        echo "<span class='form-error'>Fill in all fields!</span>";
        $errorEmpty = true;
    }
    //Check is mail adress correct
    elseif(!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<span class='form-error'> Write a valid e-mail adress!</span>";
        $errorMail = true;
    }

    //Check is username already taken
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){

        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['username']);

        if(!empty($username)){

            $username_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username = '$username'");
            $count=mysqli_num_rows($username_query);

            if($count!=0)
            {
              echo"<span class='form-error'>Username is already taken! </span>";
              $errorTaken = true;
            }
    }

}

    if($errorEmpty == false && $errorMail == false && $errorTaken == false){

            //Create user
            $add_user_sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_username, user_password, user_company, user_mail, user_adress) 
                            VALUES ('".$username ."', '".$password."', '".$company."', '".$mail."', '".$adress."')";

            $add_user_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_user_sql)
                or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

            //Close connection to MySQL
            mysqli_close($mysqli);

            echo "<span class='form-success'>Succesifuly registrated!</span>";
        }

}
```